# Providing a swipe animation for a detail DIV in angular

Tags: css, html, angular, css-animations

We have an angular (4.x) application, that has a fairly simple page.

This page has a DIV container showing information about a user (name, address, etc) which are traditional `{{binding}}` things.

There's a back/next button, which triggers a call fetching the next item, the bound object changes - UI updates, all is good.

It has been asked if we can somehow animate the screen when the "next" button is pressed - preferrably to look like a right-to-left swipe, so the new pane scrolls into view.

I'm unsure what the right approach for this is. I'm assuming I'm going to need to repeat the `DIV` (possibly 3 copies for 'previous' support as well) each bound to a different variable, and somehow cycle the DIVs around in some sort of UI ring-buffer ?

Is this the right approach, or is there some other route I could be using?

Is there some component or example I could use to get started on implementing this? All the examples I can find contain all the DIVs they're going to display up-front in the page, which doesn't help when you have no idea how many it will be (not to mention making the page huge).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you said, you need three "panels" (divs) where the variables changes for each panel. The animation can be done with css.

Start in the "middle" and then scroll at either side, and then jump into the middle again while switching out the panels.

(a) **(b)** (c)

*swipe left*

(a) (b) **(c)**

*jump*

(b) **(c)** (a)

If you don't want an infinite loop, then only scrolling is necessary.

---

You could also, instead of a slide effect, implement a rotate effect like a revolving door. Then you can manage with only one panel. You change the current div when the css animation is half-way done (when the container looks like a stroke).

Comment: So I have had some success with slick-carousel, which seems to be close to what I need. It has some issues though as I'm trying to scroll dynamic content - it "snapshots" somehow the div, so when you scroll past the end it scrolls in the snapshot, then replaces the div once it's done. As my control has expandable/contractable sections, I'm going to have to duplicate this somehow on the offscreen element.